# I can hear everything on my Samsung tab 2, but the screen won't open

Tags: lock-screens

I can hear everything on my Samsung tab 2, but the screen won't open. I've tried pressing and holding the volume and power and home button
 for 40 seconds, but it won't work. (CE0168)

Comment: What happened to the tablet? May be a damaged display then you'll need a replacement at a repair shop or by yourself if you're handy.

Comment: Is the backlight on? Check that in dark surroundings.